# Finding Interval of Integration

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals

If we let :
$$
x(t)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $0<t<1$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
h(t)=x(t/a)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $0<t<a$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
where $0<a\leq 1$
I wish to find convolution of $(x*h)(t)$ without graphing. We have that :
$$
\max(0,t-a)<\tau<\min(1,t)
$$

> Is the following assertion correct?
> $$ 
> \max(0,t-a)=\begin{cases}
> 0&\text{if $0<t<a$}\\
> t-a&\text{if $a<t<1$}
> \end{cases}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \min(t,1)=\begin{cases}
> 1&\text{if $1<t<1+a$}\\
> t&\text{if $0<t<1$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:

$$x(t)*h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)h(t-\tau) \ \mathrm{d}\tau$$

If any of the functions inside the integral equals 0, then the product does as well. We know that:

$$x(\tau)\neq0  \iff \tau\in(0,1)$$
$$h(t-\tau)\neq0  \iff t-\tau\in(0,a) \iff \tau \in (t-a,t)$$

So the convolution integral can be simplified:

$$x(t)*h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)h(t-\tau) \ \mathrm{d}\tau
= \int_{\max(0, t-a)}^{\min(1,t)} x(\tau)h(t-\tau) \ \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

Just as you had found out.

Notice that this works just because $0<a\leq 1$. If that was not the case, then some other things should be taken into account.

Comment: @MattL. If $t<0$ then $x(\tau)$ and $h(t-\tau)$ would be zero for any value of $\tau$ in the interval of integration. I don't see why you say that the result of the integral would be $t$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Somehow I overlooked that you left the integrand unchanged. I've often seen that type of integral just with $d\tau$, which is not the correct result because the integral isn't equal to zero when its lower bound exceed its upper bound. Sorry for the confusion.